# Teradata left join dropping nulls

Tags: sql, teradata

In Teradata 16.20.53.29, when I do a left join and aggregation as follows:

```
select
  b.department,
  sum(a.sales) as sales

from table1 a
  left join table2 b
    on b.product = a.product

where a.date_purchase >= '2018-01-01'
  and a.date_purchase <= '2020-01-01'
  and a.brand = 'ACME'
  and a.quantity > 0

group by 1
order by 1
```

I expect the missing rows that are in table1 and not in table2 to be included but they are not.

Output:

[image]

However, if I restructure the query like this:

```
select
   b.department,
   sum(a.sales) as sales

from table1 a
    left join table2 b
        on b.product = a.product
        and a.date_purchase >= '2018-01-01'
        and a.date_purchase <= '2020-01-01'
        and a.brand = 'ACME'
        and a.quantity > 0

group by 1
order by 1
```

Then the missing rows are included.

Output:

[image]

This is the opposite of my expectation, I would expect the first query to include the nulls and the second query to effectively become an inner join and thus exclude the nulls. Why is this happening?

Comment: You are joining by `b.department`.  What do you want when there is no match?

Comment: The second output is the output I was expecting / what I want when there is no match

Comment: . . What you are describing look like a bug in Teradata.

Comment: I  really doubt this is a bug, please post sample data from your tables.

Comment: will have to cook up a reprex as the data is sensitive, will do a bit later

Comment: @Andrew My question was answered below so not going to make a reprex anymore, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the queries and results are correct.

Case 1.
Joining on the `product` column. If some product doesn't have a matching key, `department` will be `null`. Obviously, all products can be joined, and `where` statement filters by date_purchase, brand and quantity.

Case 2.
When something in the join condition isn't met, `b` columns will be `null`. In this case when `date_purchase` is out of the range it will mark `department` as `null`.

In the following example you can see join condition has `day` condition in the future, but all records are part of the result:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3eda88/1

Comment: Does this mean that the nulls in the second output are rows where there is a product match between the tables but the brand/date/quantity conditions are not met?

Comment: yes.. try to do a simple join between products and put a purchase_date > '2050-01-01' [something in the future[. you should get all records back

Comment: thanks, this fixed my mental model of how left joins work